# Couldn't understand the humour

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, humor, jokes

Gandhi went in his loincloth to Buckingham Palace and met the king. Later, when somebody asked him if he felt that was proper, Gandhi replied: "**The king had enough for both of us.**"

Full article: https://www.nytimes.com/2004/01/21/opinion/meanwhile-gandhi-for-one-would-have-found-it-funny.html

My tiny brain couldn't grasp his reply.

Comment: The king wore enough [clothing] for both of us. In other words the king was overdressed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't vouch for my sense of humor, or for him meaning it the same way I understand it.
That being said, I think he meant that he didn't need to wear any more clothing than he did, because the king had on clothing that was an amount equivalent to being sufficient for two people.

Comment: Nicely put! Welcome to ELU, BTW.

Comment: Well said! Thank you and welcome to the community!